# How do I clear the capture window in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

Is there a way to clear the capture window in Wireshark without restarting the capture or re-applying the filter? It's difficult to tell one set of traffic from another without looking very closely at the timestamp.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I don't see a way to clear the window, but hitting 'Restart the running live capture' seems to work.

You can therefore clear the window in WireShark by doing one of the following:

- Clicking on the green shark-fin to the right of the red `Stop` button
- Clicking on `Capture` > `Restart`
- Hitting `Ctrl-R`.

Comment: Added as an Enhancement Request: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9817

Comment: On Wireshark 2 Preview, you must Stop, then Start, then 'Continue without Saving'.

Comment: If capturing from a pipe, this doesn't work - it reports the error "Unrecognized libpcap format". I think this is because it is performing some sort of operation not compatible with a pipe source. I haven't found a way to clear the capture from a pipe other than recreating the pipe and restarting wireshark.

Comment: @meowsqueak - Yes, you're right. This has also been mentioned on the Enhancement Request page: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9817#c4.

Comment: This breaks my capture for my Atmel Zigbee Sniffer :(

Comment: By the way, it means there's no way to clear the current logs without restart. That's awesome; I think I've seen that on the previous version of wireshark...

Comment: Its 2022 and I still do not think this exists. I hope I am proved wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Possible **workaround** w/o stopping/restarting capture

Suppose the last packet captured so far is the xth packet. Just apply the filter `frame.number>x` and everything disappears :)

Comment: This answer is underrated. I am using Wireshark on GNS3 and it crashes if I restart the capture. This was the only way I could get rid of the old packets.

Comment: Excellent! One technique to get that filter text is: right click on the `No.` column (No. is the frame number) on any line then `Prepare as Filter` > `Selected`. This will populate the filter text with `frame.number == NNNN` (where NNNN is the frame number you selected). Change `==` to `>` to clear everything up to that frame, or `>=` to keep that frame and everything after, etc. (Note: this is using Wireshark 4.0.6)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, `⌘r` for a restart

Comment: Just saw this and tried ctrl - e on a windows box and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
F5 button now reassign to refresh interface.

Wireshark 2.02 refresh capture display 
Ubuntu : 
Press `Close the capture file`

Windows : 
Press the Green fin `Restart current capture`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to clear the window. Just hit the refresh button multiple times fast and hit STOP in the end. It will then give a warning: "No packets captured". That's all. After this you can hit the start capture button to record your packets of concern.

If it gives a pop-up asking to save the capture on hitting refresh every-time, just disable that functionality for time being. Uncheck the "Confirm unsaved capture files" field under Preferences.

[image]